# ASP.NET Core hosted webapi shows "SyntaxError: JSON.parse" on GET request

Tags: c#, json, syntax-error, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-webapi

disclaimer: I have just started learning C# and am trying to build an ASP.NET core web api that makes requests to an SQL database. Both have now been hosted on Azure ...

... and I can successfully make requests through Postman BUT can't display readable data when making calls to the api hosted on Azure.

In the controllers

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TenantsController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly TenantContext _context;

        public TenantsController(TenantContext context) => _context = context;

        //GET: /api/tenants
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Tenant>> GetTenants()
        {
            return _context.TenantDetails;
        }
```

In the Models

```
namespace TenantsApi.Models
{
    public class Tenant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public double Rent { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TenantsApi.Models
{
    public class TenantContext : DbContext
    {
        public TenantContext(DbContextOptions<TenantContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Tenant> TenantDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Expected result should be something like:

```
[{"id": 1,
"Title": "Mr",
"FirstName":"John",
"Surname":"Smith",
"Email":"John@aol.com",
"Rent":500.00,
"Address":"1 Random Place, London, L1 1AA"}]
```

Actual result :

```
[
```

Error message: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data" only viewable on Firefox

Headers in firefox tells me:

Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 22 Aug 2019 10:23:25 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

Comment: Try this in your GetTenant method: `return Ok(_context.TenantDetails)`

Comment: Can I enquire what namespace 'OK' is being taken from please?

Comment: It comes from `ControllerBase` class which your `TenantsController ` has inherited. It is of type: `[NonAction]public virtual OkResult Ok();`

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately, apologies, I'm very new to C#, do I need to use 'using' to add a namespace ?

Comment: I do not quite understand. What error are you getting? The namespace where this class resides is: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`

Comment: The error on firefox shows: ```"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"```

It is not very descriptive enough for me to figure out whether it may be an environment setting I need to change, or if it's because I need to change a security setting in Azure to allow webaccess as opposed to enabling certain IP addresses for example

Comment: Where are you getting this error now? Are you able to get your `JSON` string after adding `return Ok(_context.TenantDetails)`? What do you see on your firefox console ?

Comment: I am not getting anything returning to the window after changing it to Ok(_context.TenantDetails), still the same JSON parse error message, could it be somethign to do with async?

Comment: Well it might be because `_context.TenantDetails` is not returning any data in the first place. Make sure that you are getting data from the DB.

Comment: It is returning data in Postman though?

Comment: then it is correctly returning your data. The problem is on how you are trying to parse this data in your client. Please show me that code so to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb

This will be good quick start for you if you are new to c# and Azure.

Also you can use below github repo:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dotnet-core-api

Here are some important points to notice:

- Please make sure to enable CORS for the hosted API.
  You can refer below doc for reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api

- By Default , SQL Azure database only allow connection from Azure app or resources. If you are trying to access it form you local machine , please make sure to add firewall rule for the same:

Please follow the below doc for the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase

Please let me know how it goes.Hoping it helps.

Comment: Hi, have followed the first tutorial and can get that up and running, but when transferring the services logic over to my local repo, it does not seem to translate.

Have also tried the third tutorial, as I feel like the two azure resources may not be communicating properly, all the connection strings etc. have been configured between the SQL Server and the Web app, but still having no luck

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by transferring the logic to local repo?

Comment: Have added the below following the Connect to SQL Db in production section of the ASP.NET Core tutorial

Still extremely new to this so am not particularly certain I know what the connection is doing.

Have added the App.UseCors() when configuring but that hasn't worked either so far

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")

services.AddDbContext<TenantContext>(options =>                     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
}

```

Comment: Still extremely new to this so am not particularly certain I know what the connection configuration is doing under the hood.